# Executing readiness.httpGet: Readiness probe failed: No such host

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, readinessprobe

The following pod definition *successfully* executes a `readinessProbe`, which makes a request to the service `service-am-i-ready` that connects to pods on the same cluster.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: ready-if-service-ready
  name: ready-if-service-ready
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx:1.16.1-alpine
    name: ready-if-service-ready
    resources: {}
    livenessProbe:                                     
      exec:
        command:
        - 'true'
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - 'wget -T2 -O- http://service-am-i-ready:80'  
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

However, if I change the `readinessProbe.exec.command` to `readinessProbe.httpGet` it doesn't work anymore:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: ready-if-service-ready
  name: ready-if-service-ready
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx:1.16.1-alpine
    name: ready-if-service-ready
    resources: {}
    livenessProbe:                                     
      exec:
        command:
        - 'true'
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:                         # Only changed this method
        host: service-am-i-ready
        path: /
        port: 80
        scheme: HTTP 
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

This is the error message I get running `kubectl po describe ready-if-service-ready`:

```
Warning  Unhealty  3m10s  (x139 over 23m)  kubelet  Readiness probe  failed: Get "http://service-am-i-ready:80/": dial tcp: lookup service-am-i-ready: no such host
```

Running `kubectl get po ready-if-service-ready` gives:

```
NAME                    READY       STATUS      RESTARTS        AGE
ready-if-service-ready  0/1         Running     0               27m
```

Why is the first readinessProbe working, but not the second one? It looks like the second readinessProbe makes a request to the same endpoint as the `wget -T2 -O- http://service-am-i-ready:80` command.

Answer (score 1):

Try following this example:

```
    httpGet:
      host:
      scheme: HTTP
      path: /
      httpHeaders:
      - name: Host
        value: service-am-i-ready
      port: 80
```

> Tip: If you need to set the Host header of the HTTP, please do so on httpHeaders, instead of the host parameter.

https://loft.sh/blog/kubernetes-readiness-probes-examples-and-common-pitfalls/#http-probe

Answer (score 1):

@glv's answer is also correct, but let me explain you why it is not working and what is the otherway

The reason is **wget** uses the **DNS resolver configured in the pod**, which is set to the Kubernetes DNS service by default.

**httpGet probe**, which is executed by the kubelet on the node hosting the pod. The kubelet **does not use the DNS resolver configured in the pod**, but rather the host's DNS resolver configuration

You can modify your readiness probe to use the IP address of the pod providing the service instead of the hostname.

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    host: (POD_IP)
    path: /
    port: 80
    scheme: HTTP
```

You can dyamically assign IP by this way as well

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: ready-if-service-ready
  name: ready-if-service-ready
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx:1.16.1-alpine
    name: ready-if-service-ready
    resources: {}
    env:
    - name: MY_POD_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.podIP
    livenessProbe:                                     
      exec:
        command:
        - 'true'
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        host: $(MY_POD_IP)
        path: /
        port: 80
        scheme: HTTP 
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Comment: Informative answer - can you provide a reference (e.g. to the relevant section in the docs)?